# Why regular expression '[a-z][0-9]+$' not work

Tags: regular-expression

I use the regular expression to handle the string "abc123".
The command below is work and return value "c123"

```
echo abc123 | grep -o [a-z][0-9]*$
```

But the command below does not work.

```
echo abc123 | grep -o [a-z][0-9]+$
```

Why do I get this result?

I knew the '*' is used to matches the preceding pattern element zero or more time, and '+' is used to matches the preceding pattern element at least one or more time.

So this situation makes me confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`+` is only a quantifier in *extended* regular expressions (ERE):

```
$ echo abc123 | grep -Eo '[a-z][0-9]+$'
c123
```

In basic regular expressions (BRE) it matches literal `+`, although you can use `\{1,\}` instead, or in GNU grep (`-o` is already a GNU extension anyway), `\+`:

```
$ echo abc123 | grep -o '[a-z][0-9]\+$'
c123
```

(note the quotes to prevent `[` and `\` from being interpreted by the shell).

Comment: Just a comment on @StéphaneChazelas' edit: `-o` is a GNU extension, but it's also available in (some) other `grep` implementations. However, `\+` in a basic regular expression is GNU-only as far as I know.

Comment: @Kusalananda, I agree it's a bit of a shortcut. Several other implementations have picked some of the GNU extensions over the years. `\+` is also found in some non-GNU implementations like busybox or ast-open. Also note that many BSDs still use a fork of an old GNU `grep`, so will support old GNU extensions like those.

Answer (score 0):

`+` in grep need to be escaped to take effect. Instead of

```
echo abc123 | grep -o [a-z][0-9]+$
```

You need to write

```
echo abc123 | grep -o '[a-z][0-9]\+$'
```

There are other characters that need to be escaped as well. It is also good practice to put your regex in single quotes.

You can also use `egrep` which is a synonym of `grep -E` and uses Extended RE, as commented by @muru.

Comment: Or use ERE with  `-E`

Comment: The escaped `+` in basic regular expressions is a non-standard GNU extension.